# How do you stack things in between a Table?

Tags: libgdx

So I understand that a `Stack` is used to overlay things on top of each other, but is it possible to sandwich something in between a `Table`? For example, let's say I build my main menu using a `Table`, but after the UI is built, I want to place a full-screen overlay right underneath my play button. How can I achieve this? Here's a simple sketch of what I'm looking for:

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that, even if I use a `Stack`, the button that I want to place on top of the overlay has to be a separate entity apart from the `Table` I want it to be a participant of, so I can't place it within the underlying `Table`'s structure.

Comment: Why don't you just disable, don't draw the unwanted buttons at all or make another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the built-in z-index ordering of `Actors`. For z-ordering to work the `Actors` **have to have the same parent**. This can be kind of tricky to do without messing up the positioning and you have to do it in a kind of "hack-y" way by using an `Image` as your overlay like this:

```
// Add to table BEFORE changing z index!
table.add(button1);
table.add(button2);
table.add(button3);
table.addActor(overlay); // addActor not add!

overlay.setFillParent(true); // Fill entire table important!

button1.setZIndex(3); // On top of overlay
overlay.setZIndex(2); // Overlay
button2.setZIndex(1); // Below overlay
button3.setZIndex(0); // Below overlay
```

- **Why addActor?** The reason we use addActor instead of add is so we can add the overlay to the table without messing up the position of the other children.
- **Why add before zIndex?** zIndex works by re-ordering the children of the actor's parent. If there are no children it cannot be re-ordered.